# How to use pattern in Java to fetch groups like 'sscanf' does in C?

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I have String `user@domain:port`

I want to fetch user, domain and port from this String.

So I created regex:

```
public static final String MATCH_USER_DOMAIN_PORT = "^([0-9,a-zA-Z-.*_]+)@([a-z0-9]+[\\.-][a-z0-9]+\\.[a-z]{2,}+):(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\\d|65[0-4]\\d{2}|6[0-4]\\d{3}|[1-5]\\d{4}|[1-9]\\d{0,3})$";
```

and this is my method in Unitest so far:

```
public void test____matchesUserDomainWithPort(){

     String identityText = "maxim@domain.com:5555";
        String user = "";
        String domain = "";
        String port = "";

        if(identityText.matches(MATCH_USER_DOMAIN_PORT))
        {                                
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(MATCH_USER_DOMAIN_PORT);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(identityText);

            user = m.group(1);
            domain= m.group(2);
            port= m.group(3);
        }

    assertEquals("maxim", user);
    assertEquals("domain.com", domain);
    assertEquals("5555", port);

}
```

I get error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.ensureMatch(Matcher.java:607)
 ....
```

in row: `user = m.group(1);`

I opened http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2v5r0

and there all seems good:

Output:

```
RegExp: /^([0-9,a-zA-Z-.*_]+@[a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\.[a-z]{2,}+:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3})$/
pattern: ^([0-9,a-zA-Z-.*_]+@[a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\.[a-z]{2,}+:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3})$
flags: 
3 capturing groups: 
   group 1: ([0-9,a-zA-Z-.*_]+@[a-z0-9]+([\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)
   group 2: ([\.-][a-z0-9]+)
   group 3: (6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3})
```

Do I miss something?

in `C` i just write: `sscanf(identityText,"%[^@]@%[^:]:%511s",user,domain,port);`

For sure I can split this text with `@` and `:` and get 3 values, but its interesting how to do that in gentle form :)

Please, help

Comment: Your regex looks wrong.  The first inner group will eat up the ".com", but another "." is required after that.  Try getting rid of the "[a-z0-9]+" between the "@" and that first inner group.

Comment: it works fine, the row: `if(identityText.matches(MATCH_USER_DOMAIN_PORT))` return `true` and i cant get 1st group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use

```
if(identityText.matches(MATCH_USER_DOMAIN_PORT)){                                
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile(MATCH_USER_DOMAIN_PORT);
     Matcher m = p.matcher(identityText);
     while(m.find()){
        user = m.group(1);
        domain= m.group(2);
        port= m.group(3);
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: I'm glad it works, and the `m.find()` is necessary, but I can't believe your second group is matching "domain.com".  Maybe I'm just confused.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think your regex is wrong.

```
public static final String MATCH_USER_DOMAIN_PORT = "^([0-9,a-zA-Z-.*_]+@[a-z0-9]+([\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*)+\\.[a-z]{2,}+:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\\d|65[0-4]\\d{2}|6[0-4]\\d{3}|[1-5]\\d{4}|[1-9]\\d{0,3})$";
```

To break it down:

- `^(`
- `[0-9,a-zA-Z-.*_]+`

  - any number of these characters, will match "maxim"
- `@`

  - will match "@"
- `[a-z0-9]+`

  - any number of these characters, will match "domain"
- `([\\.-][a-z0-9]+)*`

  - will match ".com" (or theoretically ".somethingelse.com", nice)
- `)+`

  - will make group #2 "maxim@domain.com", I believe, but what's with the "+" ?
- `\\.`

  - nothing in the input string here
- `[a-z]{2,}+`

  - is this for a country code like .eu ? Again, what's with the "+" ?
- `:`
- `(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\\d|65[0-4]\\d{2}|6[0-4]\\d{3}|[1-5]\\d{4}|[1-9]\\d{0,3})`

  - seems overly complicated - probably don't do the numeric validation with the regex
- `$`

Take a look at [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) for some advice on validation of email addresses.

Comment: Thanks for your response, maybe you are right about group view, I need shift braces. See response above,